# Texture Array getting the last index only ( C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an array of Texture so I'm doing it like this

```
[SerializeField] GameObject[] uitex = new GameObject[4];

void GetTextureFromServer()
{
    string dealer_image = "";
    var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
    {
        dealer_image += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
        dealer_image += ",";

    }
    string[] NewLinks = dealer_image.Split(',');


    for(int j = 0; j < NewLinks.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        Debug.Log("HERE ARE THE LINKS : " + NewLinks[j]);

        new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("***********.amazonaws.com/resources" + "/dealer/pic/" + NewLinks[j]),
            (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res) =>
            {
                tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
            }).Send();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < uitex.Length; i++)
    {
        uitex[i].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
    }
}
```

What i tried so far is this

```
uitex[j].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
```

But it gives me an array is out of range and i don't know why.

The problem with this code is that it always gets the last index i have so all 4 gameobject has the same all textures and that's not what i want. Could someone please help me with my problem . Thank you.

Comment: I think you mixed up array sizes. `new GameObject[4]` are 5 elements. Arrays start at 0. Also `uitex[j].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;` is definitely not possible because `j` isn't in scope.

Comment: You asked this before (few hours ago) and I flagged it as a duplicate. You deleted it and asked it again then provided a duplicate answer....Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
    {
        dealer_img += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;
        dealer_img += ",";
    }
    string[] newLinks = dealer_img.Split(',');

    for (int i = 0; i < newLinks.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var index = i;  // We need to make a local copy because C# captures variables by reference to lambdas.
        new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("***************.amazonaws.com/resources/"
            + "dealer/pic/" + newLinks[index]),
            (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res)
            =>
            {
                var tex = new Texture2D(20, 20);
                tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
                uitex[index].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
            }).Send();
    }
```

Came up with this

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you load the texture into the `tex` variable. However you don't do anything with it so when the for loop ends, the `tex` variable holds the last loaded texture which you set in your third for loop. I'm not sure what your `tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist` type holds but i would suggest this rewrite:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist.Count; i++)
{
    dealer_image += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametablelist[i].dlrimage;

    Debug.Log("HERE ARE THE LINKS : " + dealer_image);

    new BestHTTP.HTTPRequest(new System.Uri("***********.amazonaws.com/resources" + "/dealer/pic/" + dealer_image),
        (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest req, BestHTTP.HTTPResponse res) =>
        {
            tex.LoadImage(res.Data);
            uitex[i].GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = tex;
        }).Send();
}
```

There may be errors in this, as i can't really test it, but i hope you get the idea.

Comment: still got this array out of index thing sir